# Why is Python opengraph.OpenGraph not refreshing?

Tags: python, django, facebook-opengraph

I'm calling the opengraph.OpenGraph function in Django from different post request, each one with a different url but sometimes it returns the same information and I don't know why.

This is the ajax that I call many times with different urls:

```
$.post('/getInfo', {url : url})
.done(function(res){    
    console.log(res)
 }).fail(function(){
    console.log("fail")
 })
```

And the OpenGraph code:

```
import opengraph

def getInfoLink(url):
    url_original = url
    info = None
    try:
        info = opengraph.OpenGraph(url=url)
        return info
    except Exception:
        url = 'https://' + url
        try:
            info = opengraph.OpenGraph(url=url)
            return info
        except Exception:
            url = 'http://' + url_original
            try:
                info = opengraph.OpenGraph(url=url)
                return info
            except Exception:
                return None

def getInfo(request):
    url = request.POST.get('url', '')
    print(url) # prints the right url
    info = getInfoLink(url)
    print(info) # sometimes prints the same object even when different url

    return JsonResponse({'info' : info})
```

I need to have the information corresponding to each url.